# Products won't display in frontend 2.1.7

Tags: magento-2.1, amazon-web-services

None of my products are displaying in the front end. They appear fine in the admin panel, but they don't turn up in search or catalog. My categories are displaying fine, but no products in them. I flushed the cache and reindexed.

[image]

The quantity displays as 0, but I've tried changing it. When I save the product it always reverts back to 0.

I fixed a problem earlier where new static-content pages weren't appearing in front end. It was a known bug in 2.1.x (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5008) and I'm wondering if the same bug isn't affecting my products as well. I tried following the steps that worked before, but still no products displaying.

I want to use Single Store Mode, but I've tried both single store and multistore and neither has any effect.

This is a new store created from the bitnami image on AWS.

Comment: Have you tried to add product to your website ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g7je6r

Comment: Yeah, no change.

Comment: try to add the simple product to your website, too.

Comment: Solved! I added the simple product and it worked. I couldn't change the quantity of the configurable product because it had 2 products configured. Even though it said that the configurable product was in stock, I had to go in and change each of the quantities in the simple products before it would show up.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I added the simple product and it worked. I couldn't change the quantity of the configurable product because it had 2 products configured. Even though it said that the configurable product was in stock, I had to go in and change each of the quantities in the simple products before it would show up.